# Contact Embedding of odd Euclidean space to cosphere bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, contact-topology

In McDuff and Salamon's Introduction to symplectic topology. They mention that there is a contact structure on $\mathbb{R}^n \times S^{n-1}$ which
extends the standard one on $\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}$.

To be more precise,
the standard contact structure on 
$J^1\mathbb{R}^{n-1} = \mathbb{R}^{2n-1} 
= \mathbb{R}^{n-1}_x \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}_y \times \mathbb{R}_z$ 
is given by the contact form $\alpha_0 = dz - \sum_i y_i dx_i$,
and the contact form $\alpha_1$ on 
$S^\ast \mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}^n \times S^{n-1}$ is given by
restricting $ \sum_i a_i du_i$ where $(u,a)$ is the standard coordinate
for the cotangent bundle 
$T^\ast \mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$
to $S^\ast \mathbb{R}^n$.

What's an explicit formula of the map?